# How to find nullspace of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

May I know how to find the nullspace of the following matrix $ A ?$

$A = \begin{bmatrix} u & v & u+v & u-v \end{bmatrix}$, where $u, v $ are column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3.$

I have figured that column space of $A = $ span$(u,v)$ and rank $(A) + $nullity$(A)$ $= 4.$ So dimension of nullspace is $2$ or $3 \ ?$

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Ax$ is the linear combination of columns of $A$. Observe that 
$$A\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{0} \quad \text{and} \quad A\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{0}.$$

Thus both vectors are in the null space of $A$. Moreover they are linearly independent, so nullity$(A) \geq 2$.

**Assuming that $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent vectors**, we can use the rank nullity theorem to deduce that nullity$(A)=2$ and the fact that
$$\text{Null}(A)=\text{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Rank of row space = rank of column space.

The rank of the column space is 2 if the vectors $u,v$ are linearly independent (in general position), i.e., $v$ is not a scalar multiple $\lambda u$ of $u$, $\lambda\in\Bbb R$.

Since $\mbox{rank}(A) + \dim \mbox{kernel} (A) = 4$, the kernel or nullspace has dimension 2.